# Ввод строки неизвестной длины через функцию

Tags: c

Мне дали задачу реализовать ввод строк неизвестной длины с консоли. Я решил ее написать через функцию `getch()`, с помощью которой записываю введенные символы в массив до определенного стоп-символа (в данном случае enter). Для удобства решил весь код ввода занести в функцию и столкнулся с проблемой, что введенные данные после вызова функции очищаются.

Как можно решить проблему, желательно не прибегая к использованию глобальных переменных?

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void readString(char *string);

int main()
{
    char *string = NULL;
    readString(string);

    for (int t = 0; t < 10; t++)
        printf("%c", string[t]); // Для проверки вывожу первые 10 символов

    free(string);
    getch();
    return 0;
}

void readString(char *string)
{
    char symbol;
    int counter = 0;

    while(1)
    {
        symbol = getch();
        if (symbol == 13) break;
        printf("%c", symbol);
        counter++;
        string = (char*)realloc(string, counter * sizeof(char));
        string[counter - 1] = symbol;
    }
    string[counter] = '\0';

    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: **что введенные данные после вызова функции очищаются**
Вообще-то программа должна была крашнуться. 
Параметром функции нужно сделать  указатель на указатель 
void readString(char** string);

Comment: http://pcdev.ru/read-line-from-stdin/

Comment: и хорошо бы из функции возвращать длину строки

Comment: и getch() что это за функция? в стандартном С нет такой функции. Есть getchar и getc.  В Visual Studio есть _getch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Главная стандартная ошибка - аргументы в функции *передаются по значению*, т.е. здесь

```
void readString(char *string)
```

вы передаете в функцию значение указателя `string`. Когда вы меняете его - вы никак не меняете саму переданную переменную `string`.

Варианты - или передавайте в функцию адрес этой переменной

```
void readString(char **string)
...
readString(&string);
```

и внутри функции работайте с `*string` - т.е. переменной, на которую указывает аргумент, или возвращайте новое значение из функции и присваивайте его:

```
char* readString(char *string)
{
    ...
    return string;
}
....
string = readString(string);
```

Способа получения строки с помощью `getch()` я в ответе не касаюсь.

Answer (score 0):

Самая первая Ваша ошибка это:

> стоп-символа (в данном случае enter)

Не существует такого символа, как enter. Enter -- кнопочка на клавиатуре. А символ есть перехода на новую строку, а именно `'\n'`

Что касается функции записи строки, то можно реализовать, например, так:

```
void readString (char ** s, size_t * len) {
    size_t delta = 10;
    char * str = (char *) malloc (delta * sizeof (char));
    size_t size = delta;
    if (str == NULL) { throw "bad_alloc"; }
    char * buf;
    size_t n = 0;
    int c;

    while (1) {
        c = fgetc (stdin);
        if (c == EOF || c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n') { break; }

        if (n == size) {
            buf = (char *) malloc ((size + delta) * sizeof (char));
            if (buf == NULL) { throw "bad_alloc"; }
            memcpy (buf, str, size * sizeof (char));
            free (str);
            str = buf;
            size += delta;
        }

        str[n++] = c;
    }

    if (n != size) {
        buf = (char *) malloc (n * sizeof (char));
        if (buf == NULL) { throw "bad_alloc"; }
        memcpy (buf, str, n * sizeof (char));
        free (str);
        str = buf;
    }

    *len = n;
    *s = str;

    return;
}
```

Эта функция считает строку, как массив символов, но не как строку (строка завершается символов `'\0'`)

Если же необходимо реализовать, как обычную строку, то функцию можно сделать следующего вида: `void readString (char ** s)` и конец вышенаписанного кода заменить на следующий:

```
    if ((n + 1) != size) {
        buf = (char *) malloc ((n + 1) * sizeof (char));
        if (buf == NULL) { throw "bad_alloc"; }
        memcpy (buf, str, n * sizeof (char));
        free (str);
        str = buf;
    }

    str[n] = '\0';
    *s = str;

    return;
}
```

Замечу, что то, какой символ считать символом разрыва определяется в этой строке: `if (c == EOF || c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n') { break; }`. В данном примере концом строки (получается, что в данном примере под строкой больше подразумевается именно слово) считается один из символов: `' '`, `'\t'`, `'\n'`, либо конец потока.